# extra space between divs, another one

Tags: css, positioning

Not sure why do I get an extra space between my divs

http://jsfiddle.net/3cx8w/1/

It's simple as hell:

HTML:

```
<div id='menu'>
  <div id='menu-homepage'><a href='/?category=homepage'>Homepage</a></div>
  <div id='menu-prices'><a href='/?category=prices'>Prices</a></div>
  <div id='menu-contacts'><a href='/?category=contacts'>Contacts</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #343434;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#menu div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1% 2%;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 1px dotted gray;
    border-right: 1px dotted gray;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: using 
float:left 
on the inner divs will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the button divs the style

```
float:left;
```

instead of

```
display:inline-block;
```

And add this div to the end of the #menu

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Can you remove this -3px from the answer?

Comment: Edited. How do you like that

Comment: @Radio Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if that's everything (:

Comment: I just did. I doesn't let me do it until 10 minutes passed. =)